# Spark Rdd output to Kafka Topic

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a `pairRdd` constantly getting data, i want to output its contents to a kafka topic in every x mins then delete its contents.

I tried a couple stuff but each time it gave  this error.

> Exception in thread "Timer-1" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2287)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:925)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:924)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:924)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreachPartition(JavaRDDLike.scala:219)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreachPartition(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
>       at SparkProcess$1.run(SparkProcess.java:94)
>       at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
>       at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: SparkProcess$1
>   Serialization stack:
>       - object not serializable (class: SparkProcess$1, value: SparkProcess$1@28612f9b)
>       - element of array (index: 0)
>       - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
>       - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
>       - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class SparkProcess$1, functionalInterfaceMethod=org/apache/spark/api/java/function/VoidFunction.call:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V, implementation=invokeSpecial SparkProcess$1.lambda$run$e3b46054$1:(Ljava/util/Iterator;)V, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/util/Iterator;)V, numCaptured=1])
>       - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
>       - object (class SparkProcess$1$$Lambda$105/77425562, SparkProcess$1$$Lambda$105/77425562@346d59fc)
>       - field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1, name: f$12, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction)
>       - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1, )
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
>       ... 14 more

My current function looks like this;

```
   public void cacheToTopic(){

    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask()
            {
                public void run()
                {                         

                    pairRdd.foreachPartition(record->{
                        Producer<String, String> producer=createKafkaProducer();
                        ProducerRecord<String, String> data = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("output"
                                , DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(record));

                        producer.send(data);

                    });
                }
            },
            3000,      // run first occurrence after three seconds
            3000);  // run every three seconds
}
```

Comment: You should be doing for each partition, then each record within the partition, send via a Kafka producer. Or you can use structured streaming and just call writeStream. Either way, edit your question to include the errors in full please

Comment: @Jonixo Did you check this https://allegro.tech/2015/08/spark-kafka-integration.html

Comment: Updated the question with full error log and full function which is not working